# How to use input hidden fields in smarty form

Tags: forms, smarty, field, hidden

I want to use hidden field in smarty form

tell me the how i use this

i know how to add element like this

```
$form -> addElement('submit', 'submit_order', Pay, 'class = "flatButton"');
```

but i want to used hidden fields with this

Comment: What is `$form`? How do you assign $form to the Smarty template? How do you use the assigned form in the Smarty template? Please include more of your code in order to help, especially since `addElement()` is not a method in Smarty.

Comment: I agree here w/ Paul, we need more context and it should be noted that addElement() is not a native method so we need to know what exactly that does.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$form->addElement('hidden', 'fieldname', 'Text', '');
```

?